# How to identify the X button in pop-up window to close it?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

After the login there is a pop-up window that needs to be closed.
Inspect element (IE 11, GC) does not work for this pop-up window.
Questions:
- How to focus to this pop-up window (java)
- How to identify the X button in pop-up window to close it using Java?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch to the pop-up window and then close it

```
String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
String subWindowHandler = null;

Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
}
driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window

// Now you are in the popup window, perform necessary actions here
driver.close();

driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);  // switch back to parent window
```